# Doxygen sees everything as detailed description in C++ project

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I'm trying to setup Doxygen in my Qt C++ project, I documented my methods of each class in the `.cpp` file as followed:

```
/**
 * @file fragmentsfactory.cpp
 * @author Dylan Van Assche
 * @date 09 Aug 2018
 * @brief Requests a page by URI
 * @param const QUrl &uri
 * @param QObject *caller
 * @package Fragments
 * @public
 * Starts the generation process of a QRail::Fragments::Page object by
 * requesting a page by URI. When the page is ready, the pageReady signal will
 * be emitted.
 */
void QRail::Fragments::Factory::getPage(const QUrl &uri, QObject *caller)
{
    // Use processing methods to allow other extensions in the future if needed
    this->getPageByURIFromNetworkManager(uri);
    QUrlQuery query = QUrlQuery(uri);
    QDateTime departureTime = QDateTime::fromString(query.queryItemValue("departureTime"), Qt::ISODate);
    this->dispatcher()->addTarget(departureTime, caller);
}
```

When I run Doxygen in the terminal I get a lot of warning about each method. Doxygen doesn't see the comments for each method. It assumes that the comments are part of the description of the whole file.

My **DoxyFile**: https://gist.github.com/DylanVanAssche/c83c98e73f43cfb466b6d6f45da950f9

Comment: Without looking further but your example. Here the documentation block has ` @file fragmentsfactory.cpp` meaning that the documentation block is describing the file and not the method. As a consequence the method has no documentation.

Comment: Oh I must misread the docs then... I will try it!
EDIT: That doesn't change anything...

Comment: Also, I'm not sure this is legal: `@param const QUrl &uri`. I think the correct version should be either `@param uri` or `@param[in] uri` if you want to emphasize that the parameter does not return. See this: https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdparam